# Link a external C++ library to CPython

Tags: python, c++, c, cpython

I'm writing a CPython module that uses (wraps) an external C++ library, I wrote a `setup.py` containing:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

# define the extension module
my_ext = Extension("_my_ext",
                   sources=["src/my_ext.cpp"],
                   include_dirs=["src/include"],
                   extra_link_args=["-fPIC"],
                   language="c++",
                   libraries=["~/path/to/external/lib/xxx.so"],
                   extra_objects=["~/path/to/external/lib/xxx.so"])

# run the setup
setup(ext_modules=[my_ext])
```

The extension compiled successfully:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=~/path/to/external/lib1/:~/path/to/external/lib2/
running build_ext
```

But when importing the module gives the following error:

```
$ » python -c "import _my_ext"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./_my_ext.so: undefined symbol:
_ZN10my_lib6system16my_lib_functionEPKc
```

My guess is the in the linking process, right?

Comment: If it's a C++ library with a C++ API, are you using the same compiler for both the Python extension and the library? Otherwise, name mangling issues can arise. Also, is the `.so` available for loading when you do the `import`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same compiler (and machine). What do you mean about the `.so`? It is generated by `python setup.py build` with success.

Comment: What I mean is that an `.so` is a *dynamic* library. It must be available to the loader at runtime, at a path which the loader searches. I don't know the details of the exact paths, but reading up the documentation of the `ld` command and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable should be a good starting point.